# How to check if text size has exceeded tkinter Text widget size

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter Text widget that can contain text of variable length. (specifically: song lyrics and chords) I want it to make a new column if the text is too long, and similarly, I want it to lower the font size if the width of the columns is too large. I want to avoid scrollbars at all costs.

Is there a way to detect if the text size has exceeded the vertical or horizontal size of the Text widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When called with no arguments, the `xview` and `yview` methods will return a tuple of two numbers representing floating point fractions of the position of the first and last pixel displayed in the widget. If the tuple is not `(0.0,1.0)` then part of the text is not visible, meaning the text exceeds the boundaries of the window.  This is the same information that tkinter uses to manage the scrollbars.

Here is a little contrived example that shows the general idea. Run the code, and then interactively resize the window. The label at the top will change depending on whether all of the data fits or not.

```
import tkinter as tk

def resize_text(event):
    xview = event.widget.xview()
    yview = event.widget.yview()

    if xview != (0.0, 1.0) or yview != (0.0, 1.0):
        label.configure(text="it doesn't fit")
    else:
        label.configure(text="it fits")

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="")
text = tk.Text(root, wrap="none", height=4, width=20)
label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

text.bind("<Configure>", resize_text)

for i in range(10):
    if i % 4:
        text.insert("end", f"This is line {i}\n")
    else:
        text.insert("end", f"This is line {i}, and it is a little bit longer\n")
root.mainloop()
```